# My Regex equation wont work with IMPORTHTML

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've been trying to import date from the finviz table into my own google sheet so that when you import the data the the negative values also show as negative but for some reason my regex wont work.

```
=ABS(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$B16, "table", 11), 6, 8), "/*[0-9.-]+/*"))
```

Thats what i've been using, that value there should be -54.60 but it comes through as 54.60

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

A general regex pattern you may use for positive or negative floats is:

```
-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Your updated sheets code:

```
=ABS(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$B16, "table", 11), 6, 8), "/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/"))
```

Comment: just tried that and got this error, https://imgur.com/a/JcdxqWg when you enter the data without regex you get the "*" so how would i solve this?

Comment: [The regex is working in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EO9EuC/1).  Not sure about Google Sheets.

Comment: =value( regexreplace( index( importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & $B2, "table", 11), 8, 2), "\*|%", "" ) ) this works if you were interested

Answer (score 0):

Thought i'd answer with the solution

```
=value( regexreplace( index( importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & $B2, "table", 11), 8, 2), "\*|%", "" ) )
```